# Fill DropBox with value from TextBox

Tags: c#, dropbox

I've a problem with filling my dropbox with value from a textbox.
I've searched along this forum but none of the answers fiil my needs.
So:
1. I have 2 tables related like this:

Table A
ID1  Item  Active

Table B
ID2 ID1 Name Address

When I double click on my dataGridView, it opens a form (Form1) (with locked controls) and show to user the following data:

ID2 (textbox)
Name (TableA) (textbox)
Item (TableB) (textbox)
Address (textbox)

In this form, I have a button (btn_edit) and when I click that button, it opens a new form (Form2) (with unlocked controls) and shows the same data to user, but user can edit the data, including a dropbox to update Item(TableA):

ID2 (textbox) Locked control

Name (TableA) (dropbox)

Item (Table B) (textbox)

Address (textbox)

However, when I click btn_edit, the dropbox is editable but the selected value is not the value which the Form1 had is textbox.

So, here's the code in Form1 to show Data to User:

```
private void btn_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2_Edit f = new Form2_Edit();
        f.txtid1.Text = txtid1.Text;
        f.txtname.Text = txtname.Text;
        f.txtaddress.Text = txtaddress.Text;
        string s = txtitem.Text;
        string query = "SELECT TabelA.ID1 FROM TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.ID1 = TableA.ID1 WHERE '" + s + "' = TableA.Item";
        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, cs);
        cs.Open();
        object value = da.InsertCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        cs.Close();
        f.cmbItem.SelectedValue = value.ToString();
        f.Show();
    }
```

The result is a dropbox filled with all values from TableA with SelectedValue the first of the Table.

Any ideas or help?

Sorry for my nubile question.

Comment: OK, so I figured that my ComboBox was Binded to the TableA data in the Design, so I removed the binding! But, now I get the ID in the ComboBox and not the Item name.

Comment: Some more news... I can now display the SelectedValue correctly, but it misses all others values from TableA...

Comment: So, I managed to change my code, but now I'm sucked. It only shows the SelectedValue.